# R - Exclude rows from dataframe that don't contain certain values

Tags: r

I have a huge dataframe from which I need to remove rows that don't contain any values present in a vector (vector name "codes").

Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = as.integer(c(10001, 10002, 10004, 10005, 10006)), 
                 X1 = as.integer(c(150, 120, 175, 160, 1)),
                 X2 = as.integer(c(1, 1412415, 16420, 19920, 150)))
> df
     ID  X1      X2
1 10001 150       1
2 10002 120 1412415
3 10003 175   16420
4 10004 160   19920
5 10005   1     150

codes <- c(120, 150)
codes <- as.integer(codes)
```

I have tried multiple options, here's one failed example:

```
newdf <- df[do.call(paste, df[2:3]) %in% codes,]

> newdf
[1] ID X1 X2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Instead, newdf should contain rows 1, 2 and 5 with ID numbers 10001, 10002 and 10005 as such:

```
> newdf
     ID  X1      X2
1 10001 150       1
2 10002 120 1412415
5 10005   1     150
```

Comment: In base R, `subset(df, X1 %in% codes | X2 %in% codes)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way is nice, as it is scaleable to any number of columns that begin with X.

```
dplyr::filter_at(df, vars(starts_with("X")), any_vars(. %in% codes))
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr::filter()` does what you want. It takes in any condition (like is the value part of vector X) and removes all rows not matching the conditions:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
filter(X1 %in% codes | X2 %in% codes)
```